# fitted() function in R vs adding the residuals to the original data

Tags: r, regression, residuals, fitting

I've found a discrepancy between the output of the fitted() function and adding the residuals to the original data set. Is the fitted() function not doing what I think it should be doing?

Comment: Could you show the code of what you did?

Answer (score 3):

Your problem isn't with the fitted values

In fact it's not an R problem at all, but a statistical problem - one of understanding.

You have $y = \hat y + \hat \epsilon$. Hence to compute $\hat y$, you *subtract* the residuals from the data, not add.

```
mdl=lm(dist~speed,cars)
res=mdl$res          # get residuals                                 $
fit=mdl$fit          # get fitted                                    $
fit2=cars$dist-res   # get fitted by subtracting residuals           $
fit2-fit

 1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23 24 25 26 
 0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0 
27 28 29 30 31 32 33 34 35 36 37 38 39 40 41 42 43 44 45 46 47 48 49 50 
 0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
```

It works.